# DataGridView with DataTable data source: how to efficiently extract selected rows?

Tags: c#, datagridview, crystal-reports, datatable, dataset

I am showing a `DataGridView` control on my form, populating it with a `DataTable` object through the `DataSource` property of the control.  I set the control to select the entire row when it is selected, and enabled multiselect.  All of this works swimmingly.

A user can select multiple rows and click a button.  I want to make a new `DataTable` object with copies of the selected rows and pass that to a Crystal Report.

Is there an efficient means of doing this?  It seems the only way is to parse the new rows for the new `DataTable` from the selected grid cells, which strikes me as relatively ridiculous.

Comment: I'm curious if my suggestion was what you were looking for.  If not, let me know with clarifications about what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to the question "How to get selected Rows as DataTable":

1. copy structure of original DataTable
2. copy each row (as a row may exist only in one datatable object)

   ```
   DataTable selectedRows = (sourceDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).Clone();

   foreach(DataGridViewRow row in sourceDataGridView.SelectedRows) {
       selectedRows.Rows.Add((row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the best way to avoid iterating over the `DataTable` to find the rows you want is to bind to a `DataView` instead.  This way, you can sort and all that other fun stuff you like to do with a `DataGridView`, and can still get the data you need without manually parsing the underlying `DataTable`.

Below is a succinct example that should show you everything you need to get a DataRow without searching:

```
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
DataTable tb = new DataTable();
DataView dv = tb.AsDataView();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
// Get the row indexes in whatever your favorite manner is.
List<int> selectedRowIndexes = YourGetSelectedRowIndexesMethod();
foreach(int selectedRowIndex in selectedRowIndexes)
    DataRow dr = dv[selectedRowIndex].Row;
```

One quick method to get the selected indexes (just in case you need it):

```
List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    indexes.Add(row.Index);
}
```

Comment: @Gjeltama, no, I'm afraid not.  I get different errors, but this does not seem to be effectively more efficient.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I'd be curious to see your current solution that uses a `DataTable` that is similarly efficient.  I've had to do similar things with a `DataTable` in the past, and the above solution is by far the easiest and most efficient way I've found.